# php.ini file not working?

Tags: php, server

I'm taking a php course. I made a php.ini file to show errors.

I have the code below on my php.index file. But instead of the error being displayed just nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

index.php code:

```
 <?php

$test="I"m a variable!";

echo $test;

?>
```

This my php.ini code:

```
 display_errors = on
 display_startup_errors = on
```

Comment: where did you place your php.ini?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to cause an error to test the php.ini. I have both the index.php and php.ini in a php folder

Answer (score 2):

You should check your error reporting directives

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = ON
```

But please note that PARSER errors are not being show in display errors, but in error_log.

Answer (score 1):

Your file name should be `index.php` so your server can recognize it as a PHP file.

Comment: I think OP meant to have a parse error. Their intention is to see errors

Answer (score 1):

What is 'php.index'?
Normally the index page is index.php

Where is your php.ini file located?  Where is it supposed to be located?

Do you have access to php interpider (command line)?

phpinfo() can help you location the php.ini file(s)

Comment: I have index.php and php.ini in a php folder. I don't have an interpider command line. The instructor did as in my post but it worked for him in the video. I just don't know if the coding has changed since the video was made. I'm not sure why mine isn't working

Comment: <?php phpinfo();?>   Put that i  a php file called 'phpinfo.php', then navigate to that page.  See what it tells you about php.ini location.  And if your variables are being set.  (phpinfo - becomes your best friend fastly)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the php.ini file that you've created.

call phpinfo() and check the route of the php.ini to see if you are loading yours.